# Issue in getting the required data from nested json and store it in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: json, pandas, python-3.6

I have following json data-

```
{
```

'SuccessResponse': {
    'Head': {
      'RequestAction': 'GetCategoryTree',
      'RequestId': '',
      'ResponseType': 'Categories',
      'Timestamp': '2018-05-19T00:30:55+08:00'
    },
    'Body': [
      {
        'categoryId': 1902,
        'children': [
          {
            'categoryId': 10001930,
            'children': [
              {
                'categoryId': 10001958,
                'children': [

```
            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Accessories',
            'var': False
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001957,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Backpacks',
            'var': False
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001956,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Backpacks Trolley',
            'var': False
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001955,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Bags',
            'var': False
          }
        ],
        'leaf': False,
        'name': 'Kids Bags',
        'var': False
      },
      {
        'categoryId': 10001928,
        'children': [
          {
            'categoryId': 10001947,
            'children': [
              {
                'categoryId': 10001990,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Fashion backpacks',
                'var': True
              }
            ],
            'leaf': False,
            'name': 'Backpacks',
            'var': False
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001946,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Business Bags',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001948,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Crossbody Bags',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001945,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Messenger Bags',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001949,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Tote Bags',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001950,
            'children': [
              {
                'categoryId': 10001993,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Card Holders',
                'var': True
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001992,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Coin Holders & Pouches',
                'var': True
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001994,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Key Holders',
                'var': True
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001995,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Money Clips',
                'var': True
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001991,
                'children': [
                  {
                    'categoryId': 10002040,
                    'children': [

                    ],
                    'leaf': True,
                    'name': 'Fashion Wallets',
                    'var': True
                  }
                ],
                'leaf': False,
                'name': 'Wallets',
                'var': False
              }
            ],
            'leaf': False,
            'name': 'Wallets & Accessories',
            'var': False
          }
        ],
        'leaf': False,
        'name': 'Men Bags',
        'var': False
      },
      {
        'categoryId': 10001931,
        'children': [
          {
            'categoryId': 10001961,
            'children': [
              {
                'categoryId': 10002017,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Briefcases',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002020,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Laptop Backpacks',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002019,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Laptop cases',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002018,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Messenger Bags',
                'var': False
              }
            ],
            'leaf': False,
            'name': 'Laptop Bags',
            'var': False
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001959,
            'children': [
              {
                'categoryId': 10001998,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Kids Luggage',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001997,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Luggage Sets',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001996,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Suitcases',
                'var': False
              }
            ],
            'leaf': False,
            'name': 'Luggage',
            'var': False
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001960,
            'children': [
              {
                'categoryId': 10002015,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Compression Bags',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002013,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Garment Bags',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001999,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Luggage Carts',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002000,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Luggage Locks',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002001,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Luggage Scales',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002005,
                'children': [
                  {
                    'categoryId': 10002041,
                    'children': [

                    ],
                    'leaf': True,
                    'name': 'Luggage Straps',
                    'var': False
                  },
                  {
                    'categoryId': 10002042,
                    'children': [

                    ],
                    'leaf': True,
                    'name': 'Luggage Tags',
                    'var': False
                  }
                ],
                'leaf': False,
                'name': 'Luggage Straps & Tags',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002004,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Luggage protectors & covers',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002010,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Organizer Sets',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002016,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Other Packing Organizers',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002008,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Other Travel Accessories',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002002,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Passport Covers',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002012,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Shoe Bags',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002009,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Toiletries & Cosmetics Bags',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002014,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Travel Size Bottles & Containers',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002003,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Travel Wallets',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002006,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Travel adapters & Converters',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002007,
                'children': [
                  {
                    'categoryId': 10002046,
                    'children': [

                    ],
                    'leaf': True,
                    'name': 'Ear plugs',
                    'var': False
                  },
                  {
                    'categoryId': 10002045,
                    'children': [

                    ],
                    'leaf': True,
                    'name': 'Eye masks',
                    'var': False
                  },
                  {
                    'categoryId': 10002044,
                    'children': [

                    ],
                    'leaf': True,
                    'name': 'Travel pillows',
                    'var': False
                  },
                  {
                    'categoryId': 10002043,
                    'children': [

                    ],
                    'leaf': True,
                    'name': 'Travel sets',
                    'var': False
                  }
                ],
                'leaf': False,
                'name': 'Travel pillows & eye masks',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002011,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Underwear Organizers',
                'var': False
              }
            ],
            'leaf': False,
            'name': 'Travel Accessories',
            'var': False
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001962,
            'children': [
              {
                'categoryId': 10002023,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Foldable & Drawstring bags',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002022,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Waist Packs',
                'var': False
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10002021,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Weekender bags',
                'var': False
              }
            ],
            'leaf': False,
            'name': 'Travel Bags',
            'var': False
          }
        ],
        'leaf': False,
        'name': 'Travel',
        'var': False
      },
      {
        'categoryId': 10001929,
        'children': [
          {
            'categoryId': 10001951,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Backpacks',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001953,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Card Holders',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001952,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Coin Purses & Pouches',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001954,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Key Holders',
            'var': True
          }
        ],
        'leaf': False,
        'name': 'Unisex Bags',
        'var': False
      },
      {
        'categoryId': 10001927,
        'children': [
          {
            'categoryId': 10001942,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Backpacks',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001941,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Clutches',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001939,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Cross Body & Shoulder Bags',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001940,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Top-Handle Bags',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001938,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Tote Bags',
            'var': True
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001944,
            'children': [
              {
                'categoryId': 10001985,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Bag Charms & Accessories',
                'var': True
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001988,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Card Holders',
                'var': True
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001987,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Coin Purses & Pouches',
                'var': True
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001989,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Key Holders',
                'var': True
              },
              {
                'categoryId': 10001986,
                'children': [

                ],
                'leaf': True,
                'name': 'Wallets',
                'var': True
              }
            ],
            'leaf': False,
            'name': 'Wallets & Accessories',
            'var': False
          },
          {
            'categoryId': 10001943,
            'children': [

            ],
            'leaf': True,
            'name': 'Wristlets',
            'var': True
          }
        ],
        'leaf': False,
        'name': 'Women Bags',
        'var': False
      }
    ],
    'leaf': False,
    'name': 'Bags and Travel',
    'var': False
  }

]
}
```

}

Now I want to fetch 'categoryId','name' from above nested json and store it in a pandas Dataframe.

I have tried with following-

```
dfCat = json_normalize(json_data['SuccessResponse']['Body'],'children')
```

But couldn't get all values of required columns due to this nested json data.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got an approach.
Save each level of nested json in seperate dfs and then process accordingly.
I am able to proceed now.